Installed ActiveMQ Classic 6.1.4 from source via Maven, where is the installation directory?
I am new to Maven and Java with minimal experience with ActiveMQ Classic. I had originally done an installation from binary snapshot, that went just fine. The documentation I've found for accomplishing my goals all suggest modifying pom.xml or files in WEB-INF. In the interest of time I decided to attempt a source installation using Maven.
After a considerable amount of time mvn clean install completed with no errors and I see the results in the local Maven repository at ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq. There are a lot of folders in this, but no bin folder and no activemq instance to run inside it.
There is nothing new in /opt/ where other Apache products like to install and find is unable to turn up an activemq program to run either.
Years ago I set up ActiveMQ Classic, created some queues, and bridged them with remote IBM MQ queues in a single xml file and a couple IBM client libraries with no prior knowledge or issue. We're trying to upgrade to modern supported software and I can't seem to wrap my head around even running Artemis or new versions of Classic. Please help this old dog learn a new trick.

What goals do you have that you need to build the broker from source rather than just use the binary distribution? Typically only developers who are modifying the source code of the broker itself need to build it from source.

For what it's worth, using Maven to build the broker from source doesn't really "install" anything. It's not like using a package manager (e.g. deb, rpm, snap, etc.). Building the broker from source simply gives you what is already available in the binary distribution.

@JustinBertram I just want to have a couple queues our php program can interact with then connect those to a remote IBM Websphere instance. Using the binary install and porting over the client libraries, beans, and camel context from our unsupported instance of ActiveMQ resulted in a lot of errors. I have been working on updating the camel and other class references using the upgrade guides and after I cleared those I started getting errors from Kaha. Seeing as how most of the documentation for 6 is using Maven I figured I'd give that a try as deadlines approach.

I don't think using Maven to build the broker from source is going to help you. It sounds like you have a number of moving pieces here, but if you want to get a broker up and running quickly see my answer. Once you've got that going you can look at migrating the other pieces.

Also, I would recommend against running Camel routes in the same JVM as the broker. It's technically possible to do, but you almost always want to separate these two concerns so they can have independent life-cycles. Camel routes can be run standalone.

@JustinBertram Thank you for your responses, I'll give that a try. Your comment about the multiple moving pieces is where I'm getting hung up. Uusing the old, no longer supported version of Classic we're currently on it is like 50 lines of very straight forward XML that I put together in an afternoon so it felt like it wasn't multiple moving pieces, but it certainly does now.

I recommend ActiveMQ Artemis. It supports all the same protocols as ActiveMQ Classic (plus a couple more). It also has more features and better performance.
All you need to do is download the binary distribution, uncompress it, and create a broker instance, e.g.:
wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/activemq/activemq-artemis/2.39.0/apache-artemis-2.39.0-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf apache-artemis-2.39.0-bin.tar.gz
cd apache-artemis-2.39.0/bin
./artemis create ~/myBroker
cd ~/myBroker/bin
./artemis run

Assuming all the required ports are open your new broker instance will start. You can navigate to http://localhost:8161/console to use the web console and enter the credentials that you specified when you created the broker with artemis create.
